# Append vector not giving names

Tags: r, append

In R studio, I am looking to create a vector for country names. They are enclosed in my data set in column 1. Countryvec gives factor names

```
"Australia Australia ..."
```

x just gives the names of Russia, country 36, country ends up being

```
1,1,...,2,2,...,4,4.. etc.
```

They are also not in order, 3 ends up between 42 and 43. How do I make the numbers the factors?

```
gdppc=read.xlsx("H:/dissertation/ALL/YAS.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1,startRow = 1)
countryvec=gdppc[,1]
country=c()
for (j in 1:43){
  x=rep(countryvec[j],25)
  country=append(country,x)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the levels attribute

```
set.seed(7)

v <- factor(letters[rbinom(20, 10, .5)])
> c(v)
[1] 6 4 2 2 3 5 3 6 2 4 2 3 5 2 4 2 4 1 6 3

> levels(v)[v]
[1] "h" "e" "c" "c" "d" "f" "d" "h" "c" "e" "c" "d" "f" "c" "e" "c" "e" "a" "h" "d"
```

You'll probably need to modify the code to inside the loop:

```
x <- rep(levels(countryvec)[countryvec][j], 25)
```

Or convert the vector prior to the loop:

```
countryvec <- levels(countryvec)[countryvec]
```

Comment: Hi, converting the vector prior to the loop worked just great, thanks